# Can we rewrite the conditions for Tumbleweed badge?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges

So I had asked [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1241/shouldnt-i-get-tumbleweed-badge) question on Meta Superuser as to why I didn't get a Tumbleweed badge. Now the answer is right, but, it doesn't say anywhere in the description for Tumbleweed on any of the Stack Exchange sites that votes early on influence whether you get the Tumbleweed badge. All it says is:

> Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

As you can see nothing about up-votes. Thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed it to

> Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

Answer (score 1):

I think the initial rationale would have been that it has to have been at least viewed a few times to garner a few up-votes.

Now, should a low-view yet up-voted question still be qualifiable for a tumbleweed, in the spirit of what it should mean? I think so.